# ORM support for oracle object types

Tags: java, plsql, oracle11g, orm, user-defined-types

is there a java ORM library that will  natively suppport oracle object types which are used as IN/OUT parameters in PL/SQL procedures.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com';
```

Object-relational-mapping is the idea of being able to write queries like the one above, as well as much more complicated ones, using the object-oriented paradigm of your preferred programming language.

Long story short, we are trying to interact with our database using our language of choice instead of SQL.

Here’s where the Object-relational-mapper comes in. When most people say “ORM” they are referring to a library that implements this technique. For example, the above query would now look something like this:

```
    var orm = require('generic-orm-libarry');
    var user = orm("users").where({ email: 'test@test.com' });
```

As you can see, we are using an imaginary ORM library to execute the exact same query, except we can write it in JavaScript (or whatever language you’re using). We can use the same languages we know and love, and also abstract away some of the complexity of interfacing with a database.

As with any technique, there are tradeoffs that should be considered when using an ORM.

Comment: *"As you can see, we are using an imaginary ORM library"* The OP is asking for a recommendation for a **real Java ORM library** which can work with Oracle Types as Stored Procedure parameters. Such a request is off-topic for this site, but that alas doesn't change the fact that this response doesn't answer the actual question.